# Can I say: "I'm very glad to be a part of X's team"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's suppose you've just been hired by Google, so you wanna say that you're very happy to be a part of the team, would you say: "I'm really happy to be a part of Google's team"? Is the apostrophe necessary here? Or is there a better way to say the thing?

Comment: Please, please, please: never say 'wanna'. It takes one extra character and a space to write 'want to'; it's hardly arduous. This website is all about learning good English, and it helps to know the correct way of saying things (want plus infinitive) before descending into informalities which obfuscate the normal construction of sentences.

Comment: Fred2, I understand your point of view but you seem to be making a very big deal out of something really small. Although "wanna" is not considered correct in formal writing; it's used in formal speaking. Just check some speeches that former President Barack Obama made. He used it a lot. It can be considered a mistake if I'm taking a written exam, but it's not the case here. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to avoid understandable implied words,  like the word understandable in my sentence 
Anyway,  why say team? Its implied,  just say 
I'm really happy to be a part of Google.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is fine; I don't think there's a better way to say it. Yes, the apostrophe is necessary. That's the way you show the possessive case. The team belongs to Google, so it's Google's team.

You can leave out the article if you wish:

> I'm really happy to be part of Google's team.

Either one is fine.